# Postfix: Remove the software name in the email header

Tags: centos, regular-expression, postfix

I need to remove the software name in the email header. Every time when I send the emails, the postfix server sent emails at the destination the emails headers include the following:

```
by mail.example.dev (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 79D412E1A3A
```

How can I remove the `(Postfix)` information?

My idea is to send the emails without telling the SMTP server of what software I used to send the email. I tried to set a header check to REPLACE this but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I have used in the `mime_header_checks` when I used each of them:

```
/^.*\(Postfix\).*/ REPLACE
/^(.*)(Postfix)(.*)/ REPLACE ${1} ${2}
/^.*Postfix.*/ REPLACE ${1}${2}
/^(.*)(Postfix)(.*)/ REPLACE ${1}test${2}
/^\s*(Postfix)[^\n]*(.*)/ REPLACE $1
/^.*Postfix.* IGNORE
/\(Postfix\)(.*) IGNORE
/\(Postfix\)(.*)/ IGNORE
/^*.Postfix .*/ IGNORE
```

I've change my main.cf to include:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
```

Do you know how I could remove the `(Postfix)` information?

If you know how I can remove it, do you know what I need to input and what file in order to get the `(Postfix) information to be removed in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man 5 postconf`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mail_name)

```
 mail_name (default: Postfix)
     The mail system name that is displayed in  Received:  headers,  in  the
     SMTP greeting banner, and in bounced mail.
```

Comment: Thank you for post the information. Do you know in which file I can find it? like I mean in `/etc/postfix/whateveritis`?

Comment: The file to edit on CentOs 7 is `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.  This line won't be there, by default, so you'll need to add it.  Then run `postfix reload` to tell postfix to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check config file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and search for line like:

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre
```

Where you can enter command like REGEX to search for particular string and replace it, ignore it, etc.